# Nagios plugin [python] to check URL status

Tags: python, monitoring, nagios

I've a custom plug-in which checks the memSQL memory usage using the memSQL API (which returns a JSON) and as the part of the check, first I test if the URI itself is accessibly. When it's not, testing the plugin with `check_nrpe` works as expected.

```
root@dops-nagios:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins# ./check_nrpe -H 10.200.22.203 -c check_memsql_memory
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

But on the weg-gui, I see:

```
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

The URI, that I'm checking, is something like this: `http://10.200.22.201:9000/api/health_check` and the function that checks this:

```
def chk_serv(addr,port,path):

    st = re.compile(r'htt(p|ps)://s+')
    if not st.match(addr):
        if port == "443": addr = "https://" + addr
        else: addr = "http://" + addr

    path = path.lstrip('/')
    if path[0:3] == 'api': path = '/'+path
    else: path = '/api/'+path

    # Connecton status
    URI =  addr+":"+str(port)+path
    try:
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(URI,None,timeout=10)
        sts = str(resp.code)

    except urllib2.HTTPError, er:
        print("{0}".format(er))
        sys_exit(STATUS_CRITICAL)

    except urllib2.URLError, er:
        print("{0}".format(er))
        sys_exit(STATUS_CRITICAL)

    if sts in ['200', '301']:
         return json.load(resp)
    else: 
         print('Status Unknown!!'); sys_exit(STATUS_UNKNOWN)
```

Can anyone tell me what's I'm doing wrong? Is it my bad-python or bad-nagios? 
FYI, it only happens when the API is down. If just [[re]start the API, everything works just fine both from console and the gui.

Best!!

Comment: Check this and search for your error message : http://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/NRPE-Troubleshooting-and-Common-Solutions.pdf

Comment: @Dominik: It cannot be `incorrect plugin paths in the nrpe.cfg` - it only happens when the API is down. If I don't touch the Nagios and just [re]start the API, it works just fine both from the console and the web-gui. Sorry, I wasn't probably clear on this in my OP.